# Dotnetopenauth stopped working a few days ago

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I have an ASP.net MVC website which I used dotnetopenauth for to allow log in via Google, Yahoo etc. This has been working great for about 3 months but on Friday, I noticed it wasn't logging people in any longer.

The popup shows and allows me to login via Google's UI, but when I submit, it is accessing my PostLoginAssertion method and then just returning me to the same page without logging me in.

Any ideas what could be causing this? My site has had no code changes for weeks and so I don't see what could have happened. No service packs were installed on the server in the last few weeks either.

Strangely it still seems to be working ok on my local dev environment.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you include a link to your public app?

Comment: I fixed it!! Turns out the time on my server was screwed up so I updated it from the web and now I can log in no probs! Thanks for showing an interest, your code is awesome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment above, the problem was caused by the clock on the server being out by an hour and a half. This caused a lot of the open authentication to break.